# How to OleFrame in non UI thread in java?

Tags: java, swt, ui-thread

Would you please advice how to use

```
org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame
```

in non UI thread?
Creating an "OleFrame", if done in non UI thread throws.
I do know the difference between UI and non-UI thread.
What I am trying to achieve is to use `org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation` in `IRunnableWithProgress

Adding

```
for(;mShell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch(););
```

(`mShell` is given in the constructor) after each OLE call helps a bit but not enough ...

Any help will be appreciated.

```
OutlookHelper outlook = new OutlookHelper(mShell, mModel.getEmailToAddresses(), "Feedback report", emailInfo.body, attachment);
new ProgressMonitorDialog(mShell).run(true, false, outlook);
```

.

```
public class OutlookHelper implements IRunnableWithProgress {
    public void run(final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        monitor.beginTask("Sending...", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
        send(monitor);      
        monitor.done();
    }

    private void send(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InterruptedException {

        monitor.subTask("Creating OLE frame");
        // Will block UI thread here ...
        final OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(mShell, SWT.NONE);

        monitor.subTask("Starting Outlook application");
        // Will block UI thread here ...
        OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application");
        ...
    }   
}
```